# Know the parent function

Tags: matlab, function, parent

I'm wondering if there is a way to know by what function is called my function "fun_a" when running fun_a. I know that i could track the "parent function" by sending information as an argument to the "child function" but i would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is using [`dbstack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html):

```
% In a sub-function or function called by another
st = dbstack;
st(1).name % The function's name
st(2).name % The function caller's name (parent)
...
```

Another useful function is [`mfilename`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html) if you happen to just want the name of the main function and M-file in which a sub-function resides.

No idea what the computational cost of these are, but I imagine that simply passing in the function name is going to be cheaper even if less elegant.